# Jenkins DSL job configuring slave

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a DSL plugin file which creates couple of jobs like pipeline, freshly jobs. I wanted to know what would be syntax (for dsl file only not jenkinsfile) that i can run these jobs on specific agent or slave. Code sample given below. I tried to use label('JenkinsEC2Slave'),But it is actually running my DSL job on slave, not the one which are created by DSL. Labels are from ec2 plugin and they should be launched on demand.

```
pipelineJob('Build_Docker_Images') {
 label('JenkinsEC2Slave')   
configure {
     it / definition / lightweight(true)
}
triggers {
    scm('@midnight')
}
concurrentBuild(false)
parameters {
    stringParam('ECR_REPO', 'xxxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com')

}
definition {
     cpsScm {
        scm {
            scriptPath ('ci-cd/pipelines/base_docker_images/Jenkinsfile')
            git {
                branches('*/master')
                remote {
                    url ('git@github.com:xxxxxxxxxx.git')
                    credentials ('jenkins-key')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use labels to select build agents in Jenkins. `label` is also the property of JobDSL, which allows you to specify labels for a job. Quoting the [DSL viewer](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/freeStyleJob-label):

```
job('example') {
  label('x86 && ubuntu')
}
```

Comment: its some how not working,  i have updated my question with code sample

Comment: Updated the syntax, do i need to put label expression after scm or what

Comment: this looks fine for freestylejob, not for pipeline job

Comment: You won't define the agent in Job DSL then, but using pipeline's `node('label')` step.

Comment: It should work, since syntax is correct and given in DSL documentation, Need to confirm why its not working in DSL